# Printers info not refreshing while debugging

Tags: vb6

I'm having trouble debugging a specific printer paperbin problem. I seems that VB6 does not refresh/update the printer info while debugging. I have narrowed it down to a simple piece of code.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim prt As Printer

    For Each prt In Printers
        AddOutput prt.DeviceName
        AddOutput "Paperbin: " & prt.PaperBin
    Next
End Sub
```

This code loops through all the printers and shows their names and paperbin values. The `AddOutput` procedure adds it to a Textbox. When I run this code from the VB6 IDE the paperbin value is the same for all printers. When I compile this code to an executable and run it then the output shows the correct paperbin values.
I found out that when I add a watch to the the `prt` object and collapse the information that the paperbin is correctly updated. From that moment on the VB6 IDE uses that specific paperbin value for all printers.

Why is the VB6 IDE giving the wrong value while the compiled version is giving the right value?

I have tested this code on Windows 7.

**Update**

Looping by index make no difference, so using `For i = 0 to Printers.Count -1` has the same problem as using `For each prt in Printers`.

Other properties are also affected. Properties like `PrintQuality`, `PaperSize` and `Duplex` do not update. Properties `DeviceName` and `Port` are updating correctly.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've dealt with VB6, so I may not be able to help much, but you've got me curious: Do the other properties of the Printer object get updated when running within the IDE? Does it work differently if you loop by index instead of using a For Each?

Comment: Is it updating `DeviceName` correctly?

Comment: The `DeviceName` is correctly updating. Looping by index makes no difference. Other properties are also effected. I have not tested all of them but `PaperSize`, `Duplex` and `PrintQuality` have the same problem.

Comment: Which service pack level are you running?

Comment: Good point @Peter.  Link is here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9183

Comment: How do I check the service pack version? I tried following the Microsoft support at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316915 but I don't have that entry in the registry. The 'about' box in the VB6 IDE doesn't provide service pack information.

Comment: You probably don't have any of the SP's installed. Just install SP6 from the link above.

Comment: @Peter, could you post your service pack 6 comment as an answer? That did the trick and I want to give you credits for it. Please add a link to the download site so others can easily follow the same solution. Do you know if there are any downsides to upgrading to SP6?

Comment: I'm not aware of any downsides to SP6, though the typical definition of a software upgrade is "old bugs out, new bugs in". :)  They did keep fixing bugs for quite some time after VB6 came out, and it looks like you stumbled on one that they happened to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's rare to stumble upon something that looks like a platform bug, but it seems to be one in this case. I recommend installing the latest service pack (which for VB6 is [Service Pack 6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5721)) to ensure that you have the latest bugfixes. I suspect (though it is just a guess) that the reason it worked when complied but not in the IDE is that when compiled it used the VB6 runtime built in to newer versions of Windows (which includes the current service packs), but in the IDE it used the IDE's runtime (which you've indicated was not yet patched).